# Ways to return objects with constant members from a function

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose you have a class with a member variable declared constant.

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(const int const_param) : const_member_(const_param) {}

private:
    const int const_member_;
};
```

We want a function that will return an instance of this object either as a "return value"

```
Test Foo();  
Test* Foo();     
Test& Foo();
```

or as an "output parameter" (i.e. a pointer that is passed in).

```
void Foo(Test* test);
void Foo(Test** test); // maybe this is more correct?
```

Note this function is the only thing that can create the object (in the above example, `Foo` will be the only thing that knows the value of `const_param` and can thus create a `Test` object)

What would be the best way to do something like this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Why does having a `const` member make this different than having a `non-const` member?

Comment: @JaredPar I think maybe because if you're trying to return the instance as a value, for example, the `const` member has already been initialized before calling into the `Foo()` function, and you can't set the `const` value again after that? Just guessing...

Comment: I can only guess that the OP is getting at the difference between copy constructors and assignment operators. Assignment operators cannot be (automatically) generated for classes with const members, of course. Copy constructors, however, no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just return such an object by copy, unless you have good reason do avoid this design:

```
Foo make_foo()
{
  int n = get_mystery_value()
  Foo x(n);
  x.manipulate();
  return x;
}
```

If you'd rather handle the object by pointer, use `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` instead:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> make_foo()
{
  int n = roll_dice();
  auto px = std::make_shared<Foo>(n);
  px->crazy_stuff();
  return px;
};
```

Or, if you just need one handler object, use `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`.

---

A bit of explanation: Having a constant member in your object essentially means that the object itself has the semantics of a constant object. It is OK to *copy* constants, but not to reassign them, so in your typical use case you would only create an object of this class once and not reassign it. A copy constructor is automatically defined for you, so you can go straight ahead and say:

```
int main()
{
  Foo x = make_foo();
  Foo y(make_foo());   // same thing

  x.twiddle();
  y.skedaddle();

  // ...
}
```

Clearly you cannot and would not say `x = make_foo();`, because your `x` is semantically a constant thing for which reassignment doesn't make sense.

Comment: Assuming you're doing Foo a = make_foo(); Isn't it true that this wont work because you're trying to do an assignment but an assignment operator can't be generated because the members are all constants.

Comment: @Dinko: Sure, you cannot assign the result to an existing `Foo`, just like you cannot assign anything to an existing constant. I suppose that given the semantics of the class, such a situation wouldn't arise. Note that with the shared pointer you *can* assign, but of course at the expense of the de-assigned object.

Comment: so how would I use the result of this function?

Comment: @Dinko: Just as you suggested, in an initialization: `Foo x = make_foo(); x.do_more_stuff();` Copy-construction is OK.

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to understand. `Foo x = make_foo();` actually invokes the copy constructor and not the assignment operator correct?

Comment: @Dinko: Correct. It's (almost) identical to `Foo x(make_foo());`.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following, and it works fine.

`Test* Foo()

{

  Test* x = new Test(5);

  return x;

}`

I don't think you need anything fancy.

Answer (score 0):

A factory function (a function with exclusive rights to create objects of a particular type) should use that type as its return, not "return by argument."

If you must return by argument, C++ has no facility for putting the returned object on the stack as a temporary. Thus, the new object must be on the heap. Since in this case the pointer to the object, not its contents, are what you want to return, the function argument should be a modifiable pointer.

Raw pointers are usually bad news because you must remember to manually `delete` appropriately. Smart pointer classes such as `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are better practice, and `auto_ptr` is more compatible but trickier to use.

```
void Foo(unique_ptr< Test > &test) {
    test = new Test;
}
```